# Splitting String in scala ignores void fields at the end

Tags: scala, split

I'm a scala beginer, and I'm facing this issue :

From  : `"abcd ; efgh ; ijkl ; ; ; ; "`

I would like to have :  `Array["abcd ","efgh "," ijkl " , "", "" , "" ,""]`

While the split function returns : `["abcd ","efgh "," ijkl " ]`

Could Someone help please ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you run it? `"abcd ; efgh ; ijkl ; ; ; ; ".split(";")` returns just what you want

Comment: Kolmar you are right, I gave a wrong example. please see Lomig's answer !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour comes from the Java method [`split(regex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-). If you want to keep the trailing empty strings in your returned array you must use the overloaded method [`split(regex, limit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-):

```
scala> "a,b,c,,".split(",")
res0: Array[String] = Array(a, b, c)

scala> "a,b,c,,".split(",", -1)
res1: Array[String] = Array(a, b, c, "", "")
```

Note that the string given in your example actually works because you added spaces between the separators:

```
scala> "a , b , c , , ".split(",")
res2: Array[String] = Array("a ", " b ", " c ", " ", " ")
```